# composer update failed Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, laravel-4, composer-php

I have this composer file

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~4.0",
        "zizaco/confide": "~4.0@dev",
        "zizaco/entrust": "1.2.*@dev",
        "way/generators": "~2.0",
        "zurb/foundation": "5.0.3",
        "artdarek/oauth-4-laravel": "dev-master"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.4.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

when I run

```
composer update
```

I got this error

> Loading composer repositories with package information
>       Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>       Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> ```
>   Problem 1
>     - Installation request for artdarek/oauth-4-laravel dev-master -> satisfiable by artdarek/oauth-4-laravel[dev-master].
>     - artdarek/oauth-4-laravel dev-master requires lusitanian/oauth dev-master -> satisfiable by
> ```
>
> lusitanian/oauth[dev-master] but these conflict with your requirements
>   or minimum-stability.

I beleive that the error is in artdarek/oauth-4-laravel but I don't know how to reslove it, any help please?

Answer (score 1):

I found this page [Composer fails when installing a dependency of a dependency, but not when the dependency is installed directly][1] helpful and it fixes my problem, I have changed

```
"artdarek/oauth-4-laravel": "dev-master"
```

to

```
"artdarek/oauth-4-laravel": "@dev"
```

Does anyone know what is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `"lusitanian/oauth" : "dev-master"` to the `require` list. 
FYI, it is better to use specific versions since you are seeking stability :)